# std::enable_if not working as expected in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming, enable-if

I was writing a small library in C++ where I only want the template to be instantiated if it is templated on an arithmetic type and I found the following issue:

If I have the following definition of `Foo`:

```
template<typename T, typename Enable = void>
class Foo;

template<typename T>
class Foo<T, std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type> {
    Foo() = default;
    Foo( const Foo& ) = default;
    ~Foo() = default;

    template<typename U>
    Foo( std::initializer_list<U> list )
    {
        static_assert(std::is_convertible<U, T>::value, "Must use an initializer list with type convertible to T");

        for( std::size_t s = 0; s < 10; ++s )
        {
            tArray[s] = static_cast<U>(list[s]);
        }
    }

private:
    T       tArray[10];
};
```

And I try to initialize it as follows:

```
int main()
{
    Foo<int> test{ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} };

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

> `Foo<T, std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type>::Foo( std::initializer_list<U> )` [with `T=int`, `U=int`] is inaccessible

I'm new to using `std::enable_if` in TMP, but according to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) it appears that this should work. What is it that I'm missing here, or is this a bug with VS2013?

Comment: A general meta hint: If you're asking "or is it a bug in the compiler", it isn't.

Comment: @KerrekSB thats a good advise, but in the case of msvc it cold perfectly be a bug, more if we are talking about templates

Comment: @KerrekSB Indeed, it is generally the case that I have made a stupid mistake; however, not always (cf. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19526526/is-const-int2-trivially-copyable))

Comment: @Shaktal: That may be so, but if you think you have found a legitimate bug, I would expect you to have worked hard to produce a *minimal* test case that produces the bug and only the bug, and cross-check that with other compilers. I know bugs exist; my meta hint was aimed at a particular *kind* of question - the question that presents a large, unstructured code dump and says "this isn't working, is it a compiler bug"...

Comment: @Shaktal: To clarify this further: it's perfectly normal for the *answer* to be "it's a compiler bug". But that wouldn't and shouldn't be the asker's suspicion. If it were, the asker should narrow the problem down to either gain certainty that it's a bug (see above) or dismiss that option.

Comment: @KerrekSB That seems reasonable to me; I will be less cavalier when suggesting that it is a compiler bug in the future. Apologies for any offense/annoyance I caused, that wasn't my intention!

Comment: @Shaktal: No offense taken! I'm just trying to work out a good heuristic on what the answer to any given question should be based on the form, rather than content. Think of it as "Auto Stack Overflow", or "Stack Overflow 2.0, Eliza speaking" :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your initializer is declared as private. Declare it as public. And don't forget to add `typename` when using `std::enable_if<>::type`.

Edit: There is no subscript overloading in `std::initializer_list`.

```
template<typename T, typename Enable = void>
class Foo;

template<typename T>
class Foo<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type> {

public:
    Foo() = default;
    Foo( const Foo& ) = default;
    ~Foo() = default;

    template<typename U>
    Foo( std::initializer_list<U> list )
    {
        static_assert(std::is_convertible<U, T>::value, "Must use an initializer list with type convertible to T");

        for( std::size_t s = 0; s < 10; ++s )
        {
            // ERROR
            // tArray[s] = static_cast<U>(list[s]);
        }
    }

private:
    T       tArray[10];
};
```

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with `enable_if`. You didn't specify any member access control at the start of your class, and `class` members (as opposed to `struct` members) are `private` by default. Just put `public:` before your class member declarations.

Comment: *sigh* So it is!! Thank you!